# Question about the boundedness of the modulus of a function with a removable singularity.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, analytic-functions, singularity

In the solution of

$$ \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} $$

The Conway book for complex analysis state the following:

Since $\displaystyle\frac{e^{iz} - 1}{z}$ has a removable singularity at $z =0$, then $\exists M > 0$ such that

$$ |\frac{e^{iz} - 1}{z}| \leq M, |z| \leq 1$$

Why this is true ?

I know that if $f(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z = 0$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to 0} zf(z) = 0$, but how that guarantees that bound ?

Comment: **That** may not guarantee it, but the whole idea of a removable singularity is that after removing it you have a function that is analytic at $z=0$, and in particular is bounded in a neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael but, why ?  I understand that, and it's precisely my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $h:\mathbb C\to\mathbb R_+$ given by 
$$
h(x)=\begin{cases} \left|\displaystyle\frac{e^{iz} - 1}{z}\right|,&\ z\ne0\\ \ \\0,&\ z=0\end{cases}
$$
is continuous. A continuous function maps compact sets to compact sets. So $h$ maps the closed unit disc $\overline{\mathbb D}$ to a compact subset of $[0,\infty)$. Compact sets in any metric space are bounded; so there exists an interval $[0,M]$ such that $h(\overline{\mathbb D})\subset [0,M]$. In other words, 
$$
h(z)\leq M, \ \ |z|\leq1. 
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. That is what I was looking for.